# Blinded sphinx first instar caterpillars not eating

Tags: entomology

I've got several freshly-hatched Blinded Sphinx Moth caterpillars (ID'd the mother), but they don't seem interested in any of the host plants I've offered. I had birch and basswood ready, and so far it's only basswood that's even gotten a nibble. I have access to cottonwood, willow, and aspen, and will probably go pick some up soon.

My question is-- is there a reason a caterpillar would ignore a plant that is a known host for the species?

Thanks!

Cal